# Is this .htaccess rewrite even possible?

Tags: .htaccess

My co-worker is proposing a .htaccess rewrite rule to implement on our system. I'm not even sure if it's possible, and I want someone more educated than me on the subject to verify.

Here's the URL currently:

```
http://cms.phasesolutions.ca/themes/Default/page.php?slug=home
```

Here's how he wants it to show up:

```
http://cms.phasesolutions.ca/pages/home/
```

Is that possible? (where the variable for "?slug=", and the "Default" folder, are subject to change, depending which theme they're accessing and what slug they're specifying)

Let me know,
thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I suspect though that your question is actually: "How can I achieve this".

Comment: If it's possible, then yes, my question has changed :P

Comment: If Default folder is also subject to change then pretty URL should be: `http://cms.phasesolutions.ca/pages/Default/home/` or `http://cms.phasesolutions.ca/Default/home/` let me know if it is acceptable then I will post a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting a solution in case you need starting point.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

# handles /Default/home/ to /themes/Default/page.php?slug=home
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /themes/$1/$2.php?slug=home [L,QSA]
```